# encrypt column of a dataframe with my own AES key

Tags: dataframe, encryption, pyspark, aes, azure-keyvault

I would like to encrypt a column of my dataframe with an AES key which I retrieve from Azure Key vault.

I can access my Key and encrypt plain text with this code:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
from azure.keyvault.keys.crypto import CryptographyClient, EncryptionAlgorithm
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
key_client = KeyClient(vault_url="https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
key = key_client.get_key("MyKey")
crypto_client = CryptographyClient(key, credential=credential)
plaintext = b"plaintext"
result = crypto_client.encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.a128_gcm, plaintext)
decrypted = crypto_client.decrypt(result.algorithm, result.ciphertext)
```

Now I want to encrypt a column in a data frame, I want to do something like this:

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    from azure.keyvault.keys.crypto import CryptographyClient, EncryptionAlgorithm
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    key_client = KeyClient(vault_url="https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
    key = key_client.get_key("MyKey")
    crypto_client = CryptographyClient(key, credential=credential)
// How can I use my key in aes_encrypt function
    parDF1 =parDF1.withColumn('encrypted_value', F.expr("aes_encrypt(tripDistance,key,'GCM')"))
```

my question is now is it generally possible to use `aes_encrypt` with my retrieved AES key from key vault? Do you have any Idea how can I do that?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/aes_encrypt.html
Probably something like : `f"aes_encrypt(tripDistance,{key},'GCM')"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own key like this using a formatted string (`f""`) but don't forget the `'` around it:

```py
parDF1 =parDF1.withColumn('encrypted_value', F.expr(f"aes_encrypt(tripDistance,'{key}','GCM')"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but after testing your code I get this message: `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'aes_encrypt(tripDistance, CAST('<KeyVaultKey [https://my-key-vault.managedhsm.azure.net/keys/MyKey/xxxxxxxxxxxxx]>' AS BINARY), 'GCM', 'DEFAULT')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires binary type, however, 'tripDistance' is of double type.; line 1 pos 0;`

Comment: @Kaja, can you please try casting `tripDistance` to string like this: `cast(tripDistance as string)`. Make this the 1st argument and check.